# Simple update query is taking too long time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have a writer and reader cluster type of setup of RDS instances. Based on the condition we are selecting the id's from the reader and updating the table using the id(primary key) we got in the select. The update is only for 30k recorded where we have around 2 million records in the table. The simple update is taking around 30 minutes to execute. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
update table set column1=1 where id IN(id1,id2,id3,id4 etc.. 30K ids)

column1 is tinyint(1)
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: try `update yourtable force index (primary) set ...`.  if that doesn't help, try `update (select null id where 0 union all values row(id1),row(id2),row(id3)...) ids join yourtable using (id) set ...` (leave out the word "row" for mariadb)

Comment: The version is 8.0.23

Comment: Surprisingly the same update query is working fine on another server where the version is '5.7.12'

Comment: did either of the alternates I suggested help?

Comment: @ysth, sorry, but I didn't get the second alternative you mentioned.

Comment: it uses a values table constructor in a subquery instead of a from tablename to supply the ids.  then joins your table to that, causing it in theory to use the index on your table.  the `select null...union all` is just to give the id column a name; for mysql it will default to using column_0 as the column name so you could simplify it to `update (values row(id1),row(id2),...) ids join yourtable on yourtable.id=ids.column_0 set ...`

Comment: here's an example using both the more complex but more database-agnostic and the simpler syntax: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de94c6ae6bf853a9629230740a9d3f90

Comment: got it, thanks.
but what would be the reason even though id is a primary key the indexing is not getting used?

Comment: With the IN operator at some point the optimizer assumes a full table read will be faster than thousands of index lookups.  You are not the only one noticing this difference in MySQL 8.

Comment: so did either of the alternates I suggested help?  I want to know for the next time someone asks this question.

Comment: sorry for not reverting whether any of the suggestions worked or not.

@ysth, actually, I tried the forced index and it worked.

Comment: @ysth, could you please help me with the below update query? If required I can create a question for the same.
'UPDATE table SET column1=0 WHERE column1 IN(1,2);'
The update is taking around 40 mins

Comment: I am trying to update the same column where the same column is used in the WHERE clause.

the column is tinyint and has only the values of 0,1,2

Comment: you should ask a new question, and show your schema (output of `show create table yourtablename`) and explain how many rows are in the table and how many rows you will be updating.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have set a massive data inside `in` block and mysql will create a virtual table to store it and parse it

in order to solve it,you can use a temporary table to store the parameters and using `join` in your `update` sql

```
update table u
inner join parameter_tables s on
    u.id = s.id
set u.column=1
```

It would be better if your parameters are coming from another exsited table,thus no need to create a temporary table

Comment: Thanks a lot  @lucumt,
We have the required parameters and the column to be updated in the same table, any other best alternative to overcome this?

Comment: if the problem where it creating a virtual table, actually creating such a table would not help.  more likely the problem is it decided to not use an index at all.